# Building HTML Calendar Using ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a similar calendar as shown in the image below:

[calendar sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdDqD.png)

I have the following code:

```
<table>

@for(var item = Model.StartDate; item <=Model.StartDate.AddDays(7); item = item.AddDays(1))
{   
    <th>@item.ToString("ddd")</th>  

    <tr>
    <td>@item.ToString("MMM") @item.ToString("dd")</td>
    </tr>
}



</table>
```

Which of course does not render the correct result. What can I do to produce the result shown in the image? I don't care about the in-active dates.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<th>` need to be nested in `<tr>`. Also, are you just trying to create the header row?

Comment: Please check out the layout in the image which I want to create.

Comment: Yes I see the layout image, but in your code above it looks like you are only rendering out the header. Also, do you have any css?

Comment: Yes, I know I am doing it wrong. I am stuck at rendering the complete thing!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should look more like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          @for(var item = Model.StartDate; item <=Model.StartDate.AddDays(7); item = item.AddDays(1))
          {   
                <th>
                    <b>@item.ToString("ddd")</b>  
                    <div>@item.ToString("MMM") @item.ToString("dd")</div>
                </th>
           }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <!-- Load rows -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That just gives you an **un-styled** table header. If all that time range data is just static (doesn't depend on what the `StartDate`is) as it appears in the image - *you said the inactive doesn't matter* - then just write it all out

Answer (score 0):

This should get you closer (you have to fiddle with the html and times yourself);

The View:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.NumberOfDays; i++)
            {
                <th>
                    @Model.StartDate.AddDays(i).ToString("ddd")
                </th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.NumberOfDays; i++)
            {            
                <td>@Model.StartDate.AddDays(i).ToString("MMM") @Model.StartDate.AddDays(i).ToString("dd")</td>
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Action in the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()    
{    
    CalendarViewModel model = new CalendarViewModel
        {
            NumberOfDays = 7,
            StartDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        return View(model);

}
```

The Viewmodel:

```
public class CalendarViewModel
{
    public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. This would create 7 `<thead>` elements. `<thead>` elements also need `<tr>` and `<th>` elements. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp) for reference

Comment: @zgood Thank you for your comment, I have updated the answer. Hopefully it's more correct now.